# SQL: Running nested queries on a list of results

Tags: mysql, sql

So query A takes query B's resutls (a list of 4 numbers) and does a query on that. How can i use syntax on this? SQL only seems to like when i have only 1 value to use as input. Any suggestion?

```
select servers.hostname,
SUM(enm_amos_commands.successcount) AS successCommandCount, 
SUM(enm_amos_commands.failurecount) AS failedCommandCount,
ROUND(AVG(enm_amos_commands.successcount+enm_amos_commands.failureCount),0) AS avg_per_minute, 
MAX(enm_amos_commands.successcount+enm_amos_commands.failureCount) AS max_per_minute 

from enm_amos_commands, servers
where servers.id IN 
(
SELECT 
    servers.id
FROM
    servers
WHERE
    servers.hostname LIKE '%111-scp%' or servers.hostname LIKE '%111-amos%'
    and servers.siteid = 6)
```

Comment: Could you post the query you got so far?

Comment: You need to show the query, as well as sample input (the table(s) that the query is acting upon) and what you expect the result to be. As worded, the question is too broad and could be put on hold or closed.

Comment: sure done now thanks

Comment: There is no "group by".  Should it be group by servers.hostname?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `join`.  I am guessing you intend:

```
select s.hostname,
       SUM(eac.successcount) AS successCommandCount, 
       SUM(eac.failurecount) AS failedCommandCount,
       ROUND(AVG(eac.successcount + eac.failureCount), 0) AS avg_per_minute, 
       MAX(eac.successcount + eac.failureCount) AS max_per_minute 
from enm_amos_commands eac join
     servers s
     on eac.server_id = s.id
where (s.hostname like '%111-scp%' or s.hostname LIKE '%111-amos%') and
      s.siteid = 6
group by s.hostname;
```